# What time is Stack Exchange in?

Tags: support

I reached my reputation cap for today and was wondering when it will be tomorrow.. I know it is not the same time as where I am now!!

If anyone could tell me the timezone that would be amazing!

Comment: @TrevorClarke Don't worry about it. You can ask anything in meta, regardless of whether it should go on the parent site. Worst comes to worst, it will migrate. But this question is fine.

Comment: @Tichodroma All questions in this meta don't just have to be about ***this*** meta. If that was true, there wouldn't be a [support](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag.

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange works on UTC. As of now, it is 19:08 UTC.

The easy way to find out what UTC time it is is to click the achievements dropdown where your reputation changes pop up. In the top right on the grey header bar, it says "UTC time: XX:XX".

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange uses UTC time. As Eastern Region (Toronto) members use UTC-4 in Daylight Savings Time, the "new" day hits at 8:00 in the evening. You can figure out the time of this "day" at the reputation drop down thing. It will be at the top.

Hope it helps! :)